# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I'm was trying to add Ubuntu repository on Debian, but get an error:

```
Err:11 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal InRelease 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Focal Fossa 20.04 is scheduled to release in April 2020. The packages hosted by it can have multiple bugs. So refrain from using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to fix this [is to not add Ubuntu repositories to a Debian system](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

There is a package in Debian [containing the Ubuntu repository keys](https://packages.debian.org/ubuntu-keyring), if you must, you can install it. But you need to understand the risks involved.